# spring cloud gateway ribbon load balancing

Tags: netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-gateway

Trying to get spring cloud gateway to load balance across a couple of instances of our application, but just can't figure it out. We don't have a service registry at present (no Eureka etc).

I've been trying to use ribbon and have a configuration like so:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service  
  cloud:
    discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: my-service
        uri: lb://my-load-balanced-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/
        filters:
        - TestFilter
ribbon:
  eureka:
   enabled: false
my-load-balanced-service:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080, localhost:8081
```

However when I try a request to the gateway, I get a 200 response with content-length 0, and my stubs have not been hit.

I have a very basic setup, no beans defined.

How can I get ribbon to play nice / or an alternative?

Comment: Are you able to get load-balancing working with Spring Cloud Gateway and Ribbon. We also have similar requirement's when we need to configure multiple target's for the proxies exposed via spring cloud gateway

Comment: @shatk yup, all I was doing wrong was not including the dependency included in the accepted answer

Comment: With above configuration will ribbon load balancing work if one of the instance is down ? Is the health of the service verified before forwarding the request to the target ?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Not with this setup - You need to wire in an implementation of IPing to tell ribbon how to verify the health of your instances. See here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out whether `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon` dependency is on your project or not

Comment: Yup that was the solution. Ribbon classes are present without but requires this starter to get it working.

Comment: How does it load balance the request or how it performs client side load balancing?